# JS - Only allowing one file to be uploaded when using FileReader Object

Tags: javascript

In my project, I have some JS code that allows a user to select an image for their profile picture, and then that image is displayed in the browser.

I only want the user to be able to select a **single** image for their profile pic, and this **single** image should be the only image displayed in the browser after the user selects it.

However currently a user can choose multiple images for their profile pic and these multiple pics are **all** displayed in the browser beside each other.

The code below uses a `FileReader` object to allow the image to be displayed in the browser when the user selects it from the input field.

Here is my **JS** code:

```
 // profilePic is the id of my file field

  // CORRECTION HERE
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.classList.add("fixedImage");
    $("#profilePic").change(function(e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

            var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];



            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                 img.src = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            $("#profilePic").after(img);
        }
    });
```

How do I make it so the user can only select one file, as currently when a user selects one image it is displayed in the browser, but when another image is selected from the same file input, it is also shown in the browser next to the first image selected. Anybody know how to fix the issue? Thanks.

**UPDATED CODE**:

This code does not work, and nothing at all changes. Please note that I do not believe #profilePic has a `src` attribute, as it is a `file` input, and not an image element.

```
function readURL(input)
{
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e){
            $("#profilePic").attr('src',e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}


$("#profilePic").change(function(e) {
    readURL(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var img = document.createElement("img");

        img.classList.add("fixedImage");

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             img.src = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        $("#profilePic").after(img);
    }
});
```

UPDATE - HTML CODE:

```
     <form class="completeSignupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/">

                <input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profilePic" accept="image/*">
                <br>

                <input type="text" name="bio" placeholder="Add a bio:" id="bio" maxlength="140">
                <br>

            <label for="profilePic"><u></u>Click here to choose a profile photo</u></label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary doneBtn">Done</button>
     </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to allow to be able to upload just a single image as profile picture? Is that what you want?

Comment: @OmolewaStephen Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @OmolewaStephen Just one single image that a user selects, and show it in the browser using `FileReader` object.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div id="preview"></div>
<img src="dummyavatar.png" id="img"/>
```

**JS**

```
function readURL(input)
{
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e){
            $("#preview").attr('src',e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#img").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Using your code, I have corrected it here

```
  <script>
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.classList.add("fixedImage");
    $("#profilePic").change(function(e) {


            var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[0];



            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                 img.src = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            $("#profilePic").after(img);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please check my original post, as I have updated it.

Comment: The code does not work, as nothing at all changes. I believe the input field with id `profilePic` does not have a `src` attribute, which you use in the code you posted, as `profilePic` is a file input, and not an image.

Comment: Share the HTML code for this to get a better understanding.

Comment: Yes i am uploading from an input `file` field.

Comment: Please check my original post, as I updated it with the HTML code for this.

Comment: From your HTML, there two input field provided for image upload, which one are you using?

Comment: Here is what your code does, for every image you select, you create an `img` tag which is why you keep having multiple images.

Comment: The input field I am using is             <input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profilePic" accept="image/*">

Comment: Ah ok. Can you alter my code to make it create an `img` tag only for the first image selected?

Comment: So can you change the code so the code creates and `img` tag only for the first image selected from the input?

Comment: move these two lines outside the code block  `var img = document.createElement("img");` and ``` img.classList.add("fixedImage");```